# How to extract Wikipedia entity matched to CoreEntityMention (WikiDictAnnotator)

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am running CoreNLP over some text, and matching the entities found to Wikipedia entities. I want to reconstruct the sentence providing the link and other useful information for the entities found.

The CoreEntityMention has an `entity()` method, but it just returns a String.

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitylink");

// set up pipeline
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
String doc = "text goes here";
pipeline.annotate(doc);

// Iterate the sentences
for (CoreSentence sentence : doc.sentences()) {
      Go through all mentions
      for (CoreEntityMention em : sentence.entityMentions()) {
          System.out.println(em.sentence());
          // Here I would like to extract the Wikipedia entity information
          System.out.println(em.entity());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the wikipedia page url.

So `Neil_Armstrong` maps to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong`.